# Fielding Photonic radar in outer space

Tags: radar

A new type of [radar](http://tny.im/5dQ). How will [photonic radar](http://rostec.ru/en/research/tecnology/4517645) behave in outer space? What will be challenges faced by such [radar](http://lofi.phys.org/news/2014-03-fully-photonics-based-laser.html) ? How will it differ from pesa on Soyuz-MS ? Will such radar be termed as space weapon and  what resolution will such radar provide for earth observation ?

Comment: Not real new...was in use in the Shuttle program for years. You can see some examples (including a picture of one in use) in the answer to this question http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10520/docking-in-orbit

Comment: It seems more like the laser rangefinder to me and LIDAR is what used by automated robot(tesla) to follow a path or to change a lane or uav to land

Comment: That piece of equipment's formal name was the Handheld LIDAR.

Comment: Is their a difference btw laser rangefinder or laser radar here?

Comment: Yes. Rangefinder only measures the distance to a single point. LIDAR scans across a grid and builds a picture made up of many distance measurements.

Comment: Is there a diff btw laser radar and LIDAR

Comment: [LIDAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) is laser radar.

Comment: lidar is not photonic radar(here). I know what lidar is. I actually wanted to use it in something(another time). My question is based on this [tech]( http://www. )

Comment: [Tech]( http://rbth.com/defence/2016/01/21/with-new-radar-the-pak-fa-fighter-can-detect-any-stealht-aircraft_561225

Comment: http://rbth.com/defence/2016/01/21/with-new-radar-the-pak-fa-can-detech-any-stealth-aircraft_561275

Comment: It is unclear what that article is referring to. The link on radar in your question reads like it is talking about lidar. The link provided by Organic Marble shows how it has been used in space, and the answer by Hobbes indicates it limitations. If you are talking about something else, you need to clearly explain that in your question. Note that long answers are rarely given for short questions as they don't show effort on the part of the asker.

Comment: Whole question is about photon+microwave radar which operate at 10+ GHZ frequency. It never mention lidar.

Comment: Photonic radar refers to a radar that uses optical signal processing.

Comment: Both links in this question are now BROKEN!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misunderstood the question, here's another attempt.

Photonic radar refers to a radar system that uses optical signal processing.

> A laser produces a finely-tuned digital signature, which is converted into a radio frequency wave and transmitted from the radar antenna. The returning wave is also converted via laser into a digital signal free from “jitter”. The cables are replaced with fibre optics – it is cheaper, lighter and crucially – it has less interference. It’s very accurate.”

In other words, the advantage is you have less noise to deal with. That gives an increase in range and precision.

But in space, it has the same issues as ordinary radar: it's useful for distances that are common on Earth, but for distances common in space you need huge amounts of power.

Comment: Yes, LIDAR. You answered good, but i wasn't was'nt talking about Lidar.