# When sending astronauts to the ISS, how does each spacecraft sense the other?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, orbital-elements, sensors

When spacecraft with astronauts tries to dock with the ISS, are there special sensors in each used to track the other?

Does one usually do the detection, tracking and orientation in order to "catch the target" or do they move towards each other?

I'm just looking for a basic explanation, I know that the details may vary from one case to another.

Comment: Are you asking if docking can be performed automatically?

Comment: yes somehow related to this.

Comment: Russian Progress vessels dock automatically to the ISS all the time. Please add details to your question to explain exactly what you are asking. *somehow* is not an effective description.

Comment: My question is can we install any type of sensor and trackers along with Attitude and orbit control system(AOCS) that can automatically detect and orient itself accordingly so that to catch or track the target space shuttle?

Comment: Space shuttles haven't flown since 2011.  I think you have the beginning of a good question here maybe but specifics are needed. Signing out.

Comment: Instead of  _Target Space shuttle_ let's assume any target of your own choice, this question is completely scenario base.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration SE. I edited your question a bit so that it better matches the style of the site. It's not perfect but maybe it's a little clearer. Is this at least roughly what you'd like to know? You can always ask more questions, and you can search the site for [docking](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docking) to see what other questions have already been answered.

Comment: As currently written, this is a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10520/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble agreed.